# How to make mmenu.js 7.3 menu to show in right side?

Tags: html, jquery

I have used mmenu.js 7.3 version for my web page. I want it open from right side of the page. Default is left side and it is working perfectly.
Can't find a option to make it work from right side.
I have used this code

```
  $('nav#menu').mmenu({
        offCanvas: { position  : "right", zposition: "front" }
    });
```

But as per the [change log](https://mmenujs.com/docs/changelog.html) from version 7 positioning is removed from off canvas addon. What can I do kindly help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use some css to position? check the class name and use it in your custom css